# Is there a way to make something truly free scrolling div (any direction) on iOs webview

Tags: ios, webview, scroll

I want a div that can be dragged any direction and is about 4x width and 4x height of the screen.

I set the body height and width, and you can scroll it diagonally some of the time, but other times when you go to scroll it will go only straight vertically or straight horizontally. It seems to be when you start scrolling straight up, it sticks that way. Is this normal for scrolling in an oversized webview div, or is there something else that might explain this?

This is on an iPad, with a body set to width:4000px and height:3000px.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone's tendency to scroll exactly horizontally or exactly vertically is intentional, and it's usually a useful feature: if you're reading a tall column of text that *could* scroll horizontally, it's nice to be able to scroll down without worrying about accidentally moving the view from side to side as you go. As far as I'm aware there's no way to turn this behavior off.

Answer (score 0):

there is a property name directionalLockEnabled that get a bool
in scrollView class.

this will do the trick:

```
theWebView.scrollView.directionalLockEnabled = NO;
```